# Sorting Second Half of a List Not Working in Some Cases

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to sort the second half of a python list. In some cases it works some cases it does not.
This is a case that seems to fail with the program:
6 Elements
`[3,2,1,6,12,11]`

This is my code:

```
#Initalizes the lists and prompts the user for the number of elements in the list
nums = []
original = []
sorter = []
elements = int(input("Please enter number of elements in list: "))

#Prompts the user to enter an element populating the nums list
for x in range(elements):
    nums.append(input("Enter element: "))

#Copies the nums list to original and sorter to modify the list for sorting
original = nums.copy()
sorter = nums.copy()

#Removes the first half of sorter and the second half of nums
for x in range(int(elements/2)):
    nums.pop()
    sorter.pop(0)

#Sorts the sorter list
sorter.sort()

#Prints the original list as well as the concatonated nums and sorter list
print("You entered: " + str(original))
print("Sorted: " + str(nums + sorter))
```

Comment: Can you provide and input and desired output?

Comment: You are sorting strings, not numbers. `sorted(['6', '12', '11']) == ['11', '12', '6']`, not `['6', '11', '12']` or (what you seem to expect) `[6, 11, 12]`.

Comment: Also, can you say what should happen when there is an odd number of items in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inputting strings:

```
#Prompts the user to enter an element populating the nums list
for x in range(elements):
    nums.append(input("Enter element: "))
```

You want ints:

```
#Prompts the user to enter an element populating the nums list
for x in range(elements):
    nums.append(int(input("Enter element: ")))
```

Then your code works normally.

Though you may want to consider using splicing and listcomp for an easier approach:

```
elements = int(input("Please enter number of elements in list: "))
nums = [int(input("Enter element: ")) for _ in range(elements)]

sorted_nums = nums[:elements // 2] + sorted(nums[elements // 2:])

print("You entered:", nums)
print("Sorted:", sorted_nums)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you may have an easier time by indexing instead of looping:

```py
x = [3,2,1,6,12,11]
middle = int(len(x)/2)
sorted(x[middle:])
```

Output: `[6, 11, 12]`